# Reference request for studying Lie group & Lie algebra representations

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am learning representation theory of Lie groups & Lie algebras from the book by Brian Hall. Unfortunately, this does not discuss infinite dimensional representations. Which books should I study for this when I complete my study of Brian Hall's book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lecture notes of James E. Humphreys on "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category O"
might be interesting for you, also including infinite-dimensional representations of finite-dimensional Lie algebras, and much more: http://www.math.umass.edu/~jeh/bgg/main.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

You could try  Kac, Victor G. Infinite-dimensional Lie algebras. Third edition. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1990.

Here is a paper by Bernstein and Gelfand that seems pretty influential:

Bernstein, J. N.; Gelʹfand, S. I. Tensor products of finite- and infinite-dimensional representations of semisimple Lie algebras. Compositio Math.  41  (1980), no. 2, 245–285.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question. Does this book deal with infinite dimensional representations of finite dimensional Lie algebras as well or focuses entirely on infinite dimensional Lie algebras and their representations?